# trying to acquire access token for private api

Tags: python, api, oauth-2.0, python-requests, http-status-code-405

I'm trying to get access to a private API from Synthesio. Their reference materials are less than helpful.

I've tried the following...

```
requests.get("https://rest.synthesio.com/security/v2/oauth/token?grant_type=foo&scope=bar&secret=client_sectet&key=client_id").json()
```

and I receive a 405

```
{'errors': [{'code': 'invalid_method', 'meta': {'accepted': 'OPTIONS, POST', 'used': 'GET'}}]}
```

Which does not make sense since I am using an accepted method, get.

Does anyone know how I can make this work? What am I missing?

Comment: The error says you cannot use the GET method on that API endpoint, and that only the POST method is allowed. If that is not supposed to be the case, then there are one of two possibilities: either the Synthesio API has a bug, or you have the wrong URL/endpoint.

Comment: interesting thank you